# How to iterate through every letter in a vector of strings?

Tags: c++

As mentioned in the title, how do I iterate through every letter in a vector of strings?

If someone types in some words like

```
hello
random
stack
```

and then enters a letter like `e`
I want to print out which words contains the letter "e" which is "hello". So how do I check every character in the vector for that character and then print the word(s) out?

```
 for (int i {}; i < gift_bag.gifts.size(); ++i) 
    {
        if (gift_bag.gifts[i] == letter) 
        
        {
            cout << gift_bag.gifts[i] << endl;
        }
    }
```

This is what I've done but it is wrong because it check if a string is equal a character. I want to iterate through the letters in each word.

`gift_bag` is defined as `Gift_Bag_Type` which is a struct containing a `vector<string>` named `gifts`. And `letter` is `char`

Comment: [`gift_bag.gifts[i].find(letter)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Answer (score 4):

The ranged for loop and `find` function in `std::string` will help you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec = { "hello", "random", "stack" };
    constexpr char letter = 'e';

    for (const auto &str : vec)
        if (str.find(letter) != std::string::npos)
            std::cout << str << '\n'; // hello
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two loops, one to iterate through the vector, then a nested loop to iterate through the string.

```
const size_t vector_size = gift_bag.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0u; i < vector_size; ++i)
{
    std::string& s(gift_bag[i]);
    const size_t string_size = s.length();
    for (unsigned int j = 0U; j < string_size; ++j)
    {
        Process_Character(s[j]);
    }
}
```

There may be other methods, but you will need to consider that the strings may not be all the same length.